# Partition the rationals with respect to a multivariate polynomial which sends classes to classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, dynamical-systems

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $f\in R[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1}],n\geq 2$ be a polynomial.

> **Definition:** We say $f$ is **$n$-severable** over $R$ if there exists a partition (of set) $$R=\coprod_{i=1}^n R_i,R_i\neq \varnothing$$
>   such that for any sequence $\mathbf{a}=(a_{i_1},\cdots,a_{i_{n-1}}), a_{i_j}\in R_{i_j}$, $f(\mathbf{a})$ lies in $R_{i_n}$. Here $(i_1,\cdots,i_n)$ is a rearrangement of $(1,\cdots,n)$.

Let me give a somewhat trivial example. Put $R=\Bbb{Z}$ and $n=2$, one can easily show that $f(x)=x+1$ is $2$-severable with partition $\Bbb{Z}=$ {odd numbers} $\cup$ {even numbers}. On the other hand, $f(x)=2x+1$ is not $2$-severable, since it possesses a fixed point $-1$. In general, one has following result, whose proof is straightforward.

> **Claim:** For any $R$ and $f\in R[x]$, $f$ is $2$-severable if and only if there is no periodic element in $R$ of odd period under the iteration $f$.

To be honest, I haven't tried much beyond the above examples, and I feel that it is hopeless to obtain an explicit criterion for the severability of a general polynomial. So to narrow down the question, here is what I mainly interest in:

> **Question:** Is there any $n$-severable polynomial $f$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ with $n\geq3$?

For the case $n=3$, I only calculated a few linear functions $f=ax_1+bx_2$ and didn't find any satisfied one yet. Also, for any $n\geq 2$, there is an $n$-severable polynomial $n(n-1)/2-(x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1})$ over $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, so it induces a collection of $n$-severable polynomials over $\Bbb{Z}$, but I've no idea whether any of them is severable over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Any advise or guidance would be appreciated.

**Update:** I also posted it on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292701/partition-the-rationals-with-respect-to-a-multivariate-polynomial-which-sends-cl).

Comment: Since it seems you didn't find it helpful, I have downgraded my partial answer to a commentary: Your idea of using the polynomial $n(n-1)/2-(x_1+\ldots+x_{n-1})$ can be extended up to fractions of the form $\frac{a}{b}$, where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b$ is a unit (mod $n$), by using the congruence class of $ab^{-1}$ modulo $n$ as the corresponding $\mathbb{Q}_i$ of the partition. This suggests that perhaps we can say more by means of $p$-adic fields (if we can solve it for $\mathbb{Q}_p$ we would have solved it for $\mathbb{Q}$, which is contained in $\mathbb{Q}_p$).

Comment: @JoseBrox Sorry for my late reply. Yes, you've just extended the partition to the $p$-adic integers via the projection $\Bbb{Z}_p\to \Bbb{F}_p$. As far as I am concerned, however, the real problem here is to "invert $p$" in the partition (I think you might agree with me) and I highly doubt it now. Thanks anyway for your interest.

Comment: To try to show that it is impossible, I would explore Ramsey theory. This looks like a harder-than-Hales-Jewett scenario (the classes of the arguments of $f$ form the "cube", the class of the result is the assigned color), in which the polynomial form of the assignment should weigh in somehow. Perhaps some combinatorial tag (like Ramsey theory) could help, here or in MathOverflow (this problem does not seem standard nor easy...).

Comment: @JoseBrox OK, I will take a look at Ramsey theory, and I do think of posting it in MO. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, if you finally ask it there, please put here a link!